# Why does my thread not run in background?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

In the listing bellow, I expect that as I call `t.detach()` right after the line when the thread is created, the thread `t` will run in background while the `printf("quit the main function now \n")` will called and then`main` will exit.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void hello3(int* i)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        *i = *i + 1;
        printf("From new thread %d \n", *i);
        fflush(stdout);

    }

    char c = getchar();
 }

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    std::thread t(hello3, &i);
    t.detach();
    printf("quit the main function now \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

However from what it prints out on the screen it is not the case. It prints

```
From new thread 1
From new thread 2
....
From new thread 99
quit the main function now.
```

It looks like the `main` function waits until the thread finishes before it executes the command`printf("quit the main function now \n");` and exits.

Can you please explain why it is? What I am missing here?

Comment: Increase 100 to a few thousand and see what happens. With that said when I tested it on ideone the thread never printed anything.

Comment: Just because you start a thread there is nothing giving you any guarantees that it will run in parallel - it *may* execute completely serial with regards to your main thread and still be a perfectly valid thread (think for example of a single cpu machine that does not switch tasks/threads very often). Don't assume things (like concurrency) that you are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your thread is too fast.

It's able to print all 100 strings before main gets a chance to continue.

Try making the thread slower and you'll see the main `printf` before that of the thread.

Answer (score 3):

It happens, based on your OS scheduling. Moreover the speed of your thread affects the output too. If you stall the thread (change 100 to 500 for example), you will see the message first.

I just executed the code and the "quit the main function now." message appeared *first*, like this:

```
quit the main function now 
From new thread 1 
From new thread 2 
From new thread 3 
From new thread 4 
...
```

You are right about [`detach`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/):

> Detaches the thread represented by the object from the calling thread, allowing them to execute independently from each other.

but this does not guarantee that the message "quit the main function now" will appear first, although it's very likely.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like the main function waits until the thread finishes before it executes the command printf("quit the main function now \n"); and exits.

That's because when you create a thread, it gets *scheduled* for execution, but the order of events across threads is no longer sequential, ordered, or deterministic. In some runs of your program, the output of `hello3` will occur before `quit the main function now`, in some runs it'll print afterwards, and in some runs, the output will be interleaved. This is a form of Undefined Behavior normally referred to as a "Race Condition". In *most* (but not all) cases, the output of `hello3` prints last because there's some overhead (varies by the OS and processor) in setting up a thread, so the several microseconds it takes to properly build the thread and ready it for execution takes so long that the `printf` statement in your `main` function already had time to execute and `flush` before the thread was ready to run.

If you want explicit evidence that things are running concurrently, you should add more work into the main thread before the quit statement so that it becomes unlikely that the main function will finish before the thread is ready to start executing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems with your code:

1. As soon the *main* function exits, you will have undefined behaviour because the variable *i*, referenced by the detached thread, no longer exists.
2. As soon the whole process ends after the *main* function returns, the detached thread will also die.